# Swift integrating SDK using Objective-C sample code

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am working on integrating an SDK into my Swift code. The SDK sample provides Objective-C code, which I am not familiar with. The SDK sample is also written for a UI, but that is not an issue. Ignore the UI part, and just see the functions. The SDK is for using a card reader.

Here is the SDK manual and SDK code:

Manual: https://atlassian.idtechproducts.com/confluence/download/attachments/30479625/80097508-001%20iMag%20iMag%20Pro%28II%29%20SDK%20User%20Manual.pdf?api=v2

Code: https://atlassian.idtechproducts.com/confluence/download/attachments/30479625/iMagPro%20II_iOS_SDK.zip?api=v2

The SDK has a .h file and a .c file. Here is the SDK .h

iMag.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h>

#define IMLOG_INFO     @"[IM Info] "

@interface iMag : NSObject <EAAccessoryDelegate, NSStreamDelegate> {

    EASession *session;
}


-(id)init;


@property (readonly) BOOL iMagConnected;

-(NSData*) SendCMD:(NSData*)writeBuf;
-(NSData*) SendCMDGetVersion;
-(NSData*) SendCMDGetSerialNumber;

+(void) enableLogging:(BOOL)enable;

@end
```

Now below, this is the sample code that is provided. Note Mag *iReader; and -(IBAction)InitReader:(id)sender; : This is part of creating a iMag.h instance and allows the SDK to interact with the plugged in reader.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iMag.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    iMag *iReader;
    
    IBOutlet UILabel *versionLabel;
    IBOutlet UITextView *textResponse;
    IBOutlet UITextView *hexResponse;
    IBOutlet UILabel *connectedLabel;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textCMDInput;
    IBOutlet UIButton *butnSend1;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *versionLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *connectedLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textCMDInput;
@property (retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textResponse;
@property (retain) IBOutlet UITextView *hexResponse;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *butnSend1;

-(IBAction)sendCommand1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)InitReader:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)DestoryReader:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize versionLabel;
@synthesize connectedLabel;
@synthesize textResponse;
@synthesize hexResponse;
@synthesize textCMDInput;
@synthesize butnSend1;

-(IBAction)InitReader:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"YES");
    if (!isInView)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(uniAccessoryConnected:) name:@"iMagDidConnectNotification" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(uniAccessoryDisconnected:) name:@"iMagDidDisconnectNotification" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accessoryData:) name:@"iMagDidReceiveDataNotification" object:nil];
        isInView = YES;
        
        [iMag enableLogging: TRUE]; //enable info level logging
        iReader = [[iMag alloc] init];
        [self appendMessageToResults: @"init."];
    }
}
```

To keep this file simple, I am only including InitReader, which in the sample is called on ViewDidLoad. So, now if the SDK is properly initialized and connected, when you plug in the card reader, "iMagDidConnectNotification" notification is called and a function called "uniAccessoryConnected" is ran.

From the very small manual, I will include relevant information.

Init Function:

```
Format:
-(id) init
Description: Initializes a new iMag instance, builds an event notification for reader’s connection, and
builds a connection and session between the SDK and the reader. If the connections are built
successfully, fires the iMagDidConnectNotification event. To destroy the object init builds, use the
standard release function.
```

SDK notifications:

```
4.3. SDK Notification Events
4.3.1. iMagDidConnectNotification
Description: The SDK fires this event to the application when an iSmart reader is plugged into an iOS
device by the 30Pin interface.
4.3.2. iMagDidDisconnectNotification
Description: The SDK fires this event to the application when an iSmart reader is removed from an
iOS device by the 30Pin interface.
4.3.3. iMagDidReceiveDataNotification
Description: The SDK fires this event and sends card data to the application as an event parameter
when the SDK receives card data from the iMag reader.
```

Now, I am going to show you my project that I am trying to make work using the information I have gathered from the SDK sample.

ContentView.swift:

import SwiftUI

```
class InitClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var iReader = iMag()
    @Published var textResponse = "0"

    func InitReader() {
        iReader = iMag.init()
        textResponse.append("-Init")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(uniAccessoryConnected),
            name: NSNotification.Name("iMagDidConnectNotification"),
            object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(uniAccessoryDisconnected),
            name: NSNotification.Name("iMagDidDisconnectNotification"),
            object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(accessoryData),
            name: NSNotification.Name("iMagDidReceiveDataNotification"),
            object: nil)
    }
    @objc private func uniAccessoryConnected(notification: NSNotification){
        textResponse.append("-Connected")
        NSLog("CONNECTED")

    }
    @objc private func uniAccessoryDisconnected(notification: NSNotification){
        textResponse.append("-Disconnected")
        NSLog("DISCONNECTED")

    }
    @objc private func accessoryData(notification: NSNotification){
        //do stuff using the userInfo property of the notification object
    }


}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var helper : InitClass = InitClass()
    var body: some View {
        Text("HELLO WORLD")
        Text(helper.textResponse)
            .padding().onAppear {
                helper.InitReader()
            }
        Text("SEND NOTIFICATION").onTapGesture {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("iMagDidConnectNotification"), object: nil)

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

So, in my swift code I am creating notification observers and an instance of the iMag(). My code should be nearly identical to the initReader() function in the ViewController.m. Yet, when I plug in the card reader the uniAccessoryConnected() function is not ran. But, I have created a test where it sends notification to it and that successfully fires uniAccessoryConnected(). So, it is not the notification part.

At this point, I need to just figure this out. I have spent a long time on this, and I hope I provided relevant information.

Comment: If you call `iMag.enableLogging(true)` (or something similar that compiles), does the console show more infos?

Comment: Yes, actually!
On: 956 RegisteredForLocalNotifications Count: 1
[IM Info] --- init
[IM Info] --- attemptConnect.
[IM Info] iOS returned list of 0 accessories
[IM Info] --- dealloc
[IM Info] --- destroy
[IM Info] --- disconnect.
On: 976 Unregistering. RegisteredForLocalNotifications Count: 0

Comment: " iOS returned list of 0 accessories" That would seems to indicate that it didn't found the accessory...

Comment: Yes, but when app is started with it plugged in it still says that, and if I plug it in after nothing happens

Comment: I needed to add "Supported external accessory protocols" to my plist and list the reader. Now, it is recognizing my reader. So some progress is made thanks to the logging!